# 409 [{"errorCode":"BULK_API_ERROR","message":"Wrong content-type for batch (text/csv; charset=utf-8), job is of type: text/csv"}]

Tags: java, salesforce

I am working on the bulk APIs for the salesforce the batch job is working in the postman where we are loading our CSV file in the text/CSV format. But, it is not working in the java code getting the error.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEYgO.png)
And I am not giving any charset in the code as well as in postman also I just gave the content type as "text/CSV" and token it has worked in postman but in the java code it is giving me the issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should always include a reproducible code example.